# How to check for fail to register a hotkey?

Tags: vb.net

how make my app to check if it fail to register a hotkey?
which I have registered it using "RegisterHotKey" function).

I just need to know the checking method.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using P/Invoke to call `RegisterHotKey`. If so your declaration should look like the following.

```
  <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
  Private Shared Function RegisterHotKey(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Int32, ByVal fsModifier As UInt32, ByVal vk As UInt32) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
  End Function
```

With this you can check the return value of `RegisterHotKey` and if it is false, you can use `Marshal.GetLastError` to get the Win32 error code which provides more info as to why the call failed.

Comment: after some searching, i found out that just by using RegisterHotKey will give you a return value of 1 or 0 being the hotkey is taken or not. try it with a msgbox e.g.

msgbox(RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 1020, MOD_ALT, Keys.W)) 'Alt+W